# ".exe" has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc

I inherited code that runs perfectly in 32-bit, but when I change the compiler to 64 bit, I get a error if I run the code. If I step the code, it (almost always) works just to fail later. There is a lot of pointers in the code, and C++ is not my strong suite. Is it possible that somebody can pick up why the error occur?

What I need to understand is: Is it fine to create the BYTE*** first, and then the BYTE**, 
and
BYTE* is never assigned to. I don't understand how this works. I would thought that BYTE* gets assigned to first, then BYTE** and then BYTE***. Why does this work on x86, but not x64?

```
void* AllocMemory(SIZE_T dwBYTEs)
{
    void* result;
    if (dwBYTEs > 0)
    {
        result = malloc(dwBYTEs);
        if (result != NULL)
            return result;
    }
    return 0;
}

BYTE** CreateBytes(int arg_0, int arg_4, int arg_8)
{
    BYTE** hedi = (BYTE**)AllocMemory(arg_0 * 4);
    if (!hedi)return 0;
    hedi[0] = (BYTE*)AllocMemory(arg_0 * arg_8 * arg_4);
    if (!hedi[0]) {
        delete(hedi);
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = arg_0 - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        hedi[arg_0 - 1 - i + 1] = &hedi[0][arg_4 * arg_8 * (arg_0 - 1 - i + 1)];
    }
    return hedi;
}

BYTE*** CreateItem(int arg_0, int arg_4, int arg_8)
{
    BYTE*** hebp = (BYTE***)AllocMemory(arg_8 * 4);
    hebp[0] = (BYTE**)CreateBytes(arg_0, arg_4 * arg_8, 1);
    if (!hebp[0])
    {
        delete(hebp);
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < arg_8; i++) {
        hebp[i] = (BYTE**)AllocMemory(arg_0 * 4);
        if (hebp[i]) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arg_0; j++) {//eax
                hebp[i][j] = &hebp[0][j][i];
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {//esi
                delete(hebp[j - i]);
            }
            delete(hebp[0]);
            delete(hebp);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return hebp;
}
```

Comment: `BYTE*** ` OMG.

Comment: Tell me about it

Comment: Also, this code has undefined behavior as it is using `malloc` with `delete` instead of `new`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854210/behaviour-of-malloc-with-delete-in-c

Comment: @Jaques for what it's worth `delete` should never be called on `malloc`ed memory.. this code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the memory issues now. The Answer below sorted it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your problem: `AllocMemory(arg_0 * 4)`

On a 32-bit system the size of pointers are 32 bits, i.e. four bytes. On a 64-bit system pointers are 64 bits, *eight* bytes. Use correct sizes (using the `sizeof` operator) and it should work fine.

---

For example, in the `CreateBytes` function you have

```
BYTE** hedi = (BYTE**)AllocMemory(arg_0 * 4);
```

Replace that with

```
BYTE** hedi = (BYTE**)AllocMemory(arg_0 * sizeof *hedi);
```

---

There are also many other problems, like the code allocating memory with `malloc` and freeing it with `delete`. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

And I wont even mention the naming of variables or lack of comments...

Comment: Haven't seen you for quite a while.

Comment: Like I said, I inherited the code. So I'm fixing up some issues, and get it to run 64bit. Your solution worked. Thanks