# How to point an array inside a dynamic array to something?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, linked-list

I have a `struct` like this:

```
struct Key_Node
{
    int key;
    struct Package_Node *next_package;
};
```

I will create a dynamic array "`struct Key_Node arrayMain[X]`" where the value of `X` will be entered by the user and depending on it I will create the dynamic array.

Since I don't know the size of the array, obviously I can not point each pointer of the dynamic array to something. So what will I have to do here?

I have another `struct` that looks like this.

```
struct Package_Node
{
    int bar_code;
    float package_weight;
    struct Package_Node *next_packaged;
};
```

`Key_Node mainArray[dynamicvalue]` and

`package_node totalPackages[dynamicvalue]`

are a dynamic array and linked list in order. I will be creating random packages and will sort them using hashtable methods. If my `X` is 3 and my random barcode is 10, I will be doing `10 % 3` which results 1, so the random `package_node` will be added to `mainArray[1]` and the list will grow like that.

Comment: Why not use a vector? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: You need another element of your struct, of type `std::size_t`, where you store the length of the array.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  What is this "next_package"?  Why not use std::vector instead of a C-style array?

Comment: Of course there is a certain chance that the answer to this will be given implicitly  by the answers to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193733/dynamic-memory-hash-table-linked-list).

Comment: @ruben2020 I can not use vectors as they are not yet covered in class. I know it sucks :(

Comment: @JohnZwinck I am trying to point Next_Package so that I can add a linked list to it later.

Comment: @jogojapan what will I then do with the length of the array? Make a loop?

Comment: @Dave: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/147331)

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I didnt know you can tag it as homework, I am new to this site. My array is generated at the very beginning by asking a user input.Key is the array that will hold the linked list. key[0] will hold a linkedlist....key[1] will hold some other linked list, etc. Next_Package is the pointer that will point to the linked list.

Comment: @Johnysweb: ah, didn't know that. user2086751: Sorry, ignore the homework tag bit. I'm out-of-date! Can you update your question with some more context? You're much more likely to get an answer that way. (by context I mean more code or a better explanation of how you're expecting this to work)

Comment: @user2086751: "`key[0]` will hold a linkedlist....`key[1]` will hold some other linked list, *etc*.". This does not make sense. `key` is an `int` in the code above. You're going to have to provide us with more information in order for us to help you solve this. I recommend reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints first.

Comment: @Dave I added more info if it helps.

Comment: @user2086751: What is your understood meaning of the term "dynamic array"?

Comment: @Johnsyweb pointer under key[0] will point to a linked list

Comment: @Johnsyweb A dynamic array is an array of which the size is unknown and will can change depending upon the size the user inputs, correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: Both runs at this question resulting in "this doesn't make sense" responses should be an indicator that either your approach to solving your assignment needs to be rethought, or the question itself needs serious work, or both. From what I see I wouldn't use a linked list at all (which technically you're not anyway. Ex: you said your array will be sized to X "where the value of X will be entered by the user". The *next sentence* says "Since I don't know the size of the array..." Um. yeah, you do, you just *told* us it is **X**. Rethink this and fix **this** question (don't open another one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need a little help to get you started.  Looks like you are being asked to implement a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  In `C` you use `malloc` to allocate dynamic storage, in `C++` you use `new`, see [In what cases do I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new/)

This should get you started, hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Key_Node
{
    int key;
    struct Package_Node *next_package;
};

struct Package_Node
{
    int bar_code;
    float package_weight;
    struct Package_Node *next_packaged;
};

int main() {
    size_t X;
    std::cout << "Enter X: ";
    std::cin >> X;
    Key_Node *mainArray = new Key_Node[X];

    for(size_t i=0; i<X; ++i) {
        mainArray[i].next_package = NULL;
    }

    //-- Rest of your program goes here

    delete [] mainArray;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I understand, but I might be way-off.

Important note: This is C++, but I can't be sure you're not actually using C (which is more complicated). The code you posted so far and the task you're trying to perform feel like C.

First, a quick intro to linked lists. They have a "head" element, and then each element points to the next one in the list:

```
struct Item {
    Item *next;
    // data here
};

struct ItemList {
    Item *first;
};

ItemList myList;
myList.first = new Item( );
myList.first->next = new Item( );
myList.first->next->next = new Item( );
```

This is a silly way to set up a linked list, but demonstrates the structure; we find the nodes by going through each element one at a time.

You want a hash table which uses linked lists (from what I can gather). That means you'll have a fixed-length array of linked lists, and the ability to add items to it:

```
struct Item {
    Item *next;
    int key;
    int something;
};

struct ItemList {
    Item *first;
};

const int NUM_BUCKETS = 3;

ItemList keys[NUM_BUCKETS];

Item *addItemKey( int key, Item *o ) {
    int index = key % NUM_BUCKETS;
    if( keys[index].first != NULL ) {
        o->next = keys[index].first;
    }
    o->key = key;
    keys[index].first = o;
    return o;
}

int main( ) {
    Item *myItem1 = addItemKey( 10, new Item( ) );
    myItem1->something = 7;
    Item *myItem2 = addItemKey( 5, new Item( ) );
    myItem2->something = 3;
}
```

So what does that do? Well addItemKey will put the Item you give it into one of the "buckets" of the hash table. If there was already an item there, it pushes it to become the second item. It also returns the item as a convenience. It's important you understand what's going on here, so spend some time playing with the sample I link to at the end of this post.

To find an item from a key, you have to calculate *index* again and loop through the corresponding list until one of the items matches:

```
Item *findItemKey( int key ) {
    int index = key % NUM_BUCKETS;
    Item *test = keys[index].first;
    while( test != NULL ) {
        if( test->key == key ) {
            return test;
        }
        test = test->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main( ) {
    // set up the items as before here

    Item *myFoundItem = findItemKey( 10 );
    if( myFoundItem != NULL ) {
        cout << myFoundItem->something << endl; // should say 7 with the code above
    }
}
```

See it working here: http://codepad.org/b03NxST2

Things to change:

1. This isn't set up for your problem. That's intentional; you wouldn't learn anything if I did it for you!
2. The keys array has a fixed size at compile-time. See if you can mix this with @amdn's sample to let the user choose a size.
3. The ItemList struct isn't needed at all really; I only included it for clarity. See if you can remove it.
4. This uses global values, which are a bad idea in general. You should use object methods, but that's probably a bit advanced for you right now.

If you ever need to do this for real, you should look at these standard objects which do all this for you:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/