# Assignment of string to structure element

Tags: c++

My program crashes when I try to assign a string value to a member of a structure.
My suspicion is that the member (of type string) within the structure was never properly allocated in memory.

Here is my code for reference:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct DataRow
{
    std::string result;
    float temp;
    struct DataRow* next;
};

int main( )
{
    DataRow* node = (DataRow*)malloc(sizeof(DataRow));    // Allocation of memory for struct here

    int currentLoc = 0;
    std::string dataLine = "HUUI 16:35:58 54.4 25.1 PDJ 1 MEME PPP PS$% sc3 BoomBoom SuperPower P0 123 25.86 0 11.1 1.0 50.0 W [2.0,0.28] 1.15 [5,6,100]";
    std::string dataWord;

    std::stringstream sDataLine( dataLine );

    while ( sDataLine >> dataWord )
    {
        if( currentLoc == 0 )
        {   node->result = dataWord;        } // <-- Problem occurs here    
        else if ( currentLoc == 3 )
        {   node->temp = atof(dataWord.c_str());        }  // <-- This code works no problem on it's own        
        else
        {       }

        currentLoc++;           
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code fails at `node->result = dataWord`. But if I comment out this if statement, and leave only the `node->temp=atof(dataWord.c_str());` the code works no problem.

How do I achieve proper memory allocation for the string member of the DataRow struct?

Comment: You never check the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: No crash occurs for me using MinGW on Windows. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Where is `node->result` constructed? You must *have* a `std::string` before you can use it on the left side of an assignment!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`malloc` doesn't ensure any constructors of the members of your `struct` are called. In C++ `struct` is basically the same as `class`, the only difference is that members are `public` by default rather than `private`. So you should `new` the object/struct, and `delete` it when done.

Comment: `malloc()` does not guarantee that the contents of the allocated memory are initialized to anything at all. You could use `calloc()` instead, which at least zeros out the memory. But using `new` is the *correct* approach.

Comment: One more difference between `class` and `struct` (irrelevant in this case): `struct`'s base classes are `public` by default.

Answer (score 6):

The way you are allocating `node` is incorrect: if you want to dynamically allocate non-POD types in C++, you need to use `new`, since it will call the required constructors (followed by a call to `delete` when appropriate).

But it might be simpler to allocate an automatic instance:

```
DataRow node;
```

If you do need a pointer, make sure to have a look at [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), particularly [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). See also [`boost::scoped_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm).

Answer (score 4):

In C++ use 'new' instead of 'malloc'. Using malloc does not run the constructor of your class, so the string is not initialized.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a  new  struct and not use malloc at all.

So use:

```
DataRow* node = new DataRow;
```

you should also take care of cleaning it up like so:

```
delete node;
```

and in case you don't want to allocate it from the heap you can do this as well:

```
DataRow node;
```

Answer (score 0):

So before I get to answering your question I just wanted to say that you should not use Malloc in c++ unless you are forced to. This answer explains why fairly well.

[In what cases do I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)

With that said changing this line

```
DataRow* node = (DataRow*)malloc(sizeof(DataRow));
```

To this

```
DataRow* node = new DataRow;
```

Will fix your problem