# How should I cast the result of malloc in C++?

Tags: c++

Please note this question is not about `malloc` in C or `malloc` vs `new`/smart pointers in C++.

If I use `malloc` in C++, what kind of cast should I use? The following all work.

```
int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof (int));
int *b = static_cast<int *>(malloc(sizeof (int)));
int *c = reinterpret_cast<int *>(malloc(sizeof (int)));
```

Live example:
http://ideone.com/lzfxcm

I prefer to use C++ style casts in my code as much as possible and I want to adopt safe coding habits. Please advise with this in mind.

Thank you.

Comment: for malloc, a C style cast is no less safe than reintprerpt_cast.

Comment: to be safe you should use new and not malloc

Comment: @claptrap I specifically stated this question is NOT about malloc vs new. Sometimes malloc is used in C++. It happens.

Comment: `(int *)` does the job right, less to type, easy to read.

Comment: @NeilKirk: "Sometimes malloc is used in C++" When, exactly? Give at least one scenario.

Comment: @NeilKirk sigterm is right, I can't think of any situation where one would prefer malloc over new in C++. Even if it doesn't matter at all, I would still stick to conventions and use new.

Comment: @SigTerm: When you're implementing a custom allocator. Of course, you won't be casting the result in that case; I can't imagine any situation where this question would be relevent.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Unless I'm missing something, even with custom allocator you'll either use your own memory functions (that are not malloc), or you can allocate memory block via `new char*`. So even in this case it isn't exaclty required.

Comment: @SigTerm: If you're replacing the global `operator new`, then you can't use `new` in there; that will recursively call your operator. So you'll need something else to give you raw memory - such as `malloc`. (But we're getting very off-topic here).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: "But we're getting very off-topic here" Maybe. My point was that even when you're overriding global operator new and/or write allocators, there's a very good chance that you won't be using malloc directly. So this scenario is very rare.

Comment: @SigTerm: When you're calling C functions requiring/returning an allocated block of memory to write to. We (usually) have no control over the libraries we use. Rather than use new (and let the library use free()) or use delete (while the library uses malloc()), it's simpler to just use malloc/free.

Answer (score 13):

Since `malloc` returns a pointer to `void`, there is no reason to use a C++ - style cast on the pointer: you get a chunk of raw memory, with no structure behind it, so the only thing your can tell the compiler by adding a cast is that you plan to use this memory for data of a particular kind. Compiler must agree with you on that, because it has no additional information to double-check your decision. Neither `static_cast<T>` nor the `reinterpret_cast<T>` offer a particular advantage over the C-style cast, and the C-style cast is shorter.

From the personal perspective, I looked at a lot of C++ code, but I've never seen a C++ - style cast used with `malloc`, only the C-style.

Comment: After all `malloc` is C! C++ has `new`.

Answer (score 13):

I would prefer to use `static_cast`, as what you are doing is converting a `void*` to a pointer to some other object type, which is well defined in C++.

C-style cast should not be used in C++, as the compiler will perform no type checking whatsoever - by using a C-style cast, you lose all type safety. The idea is to restrict your casts to only what is needed and no more.

`reinterpret_cast` has a different purpose - to reinterpret the bits of an object as some other type. `void` is not an object, so this clearly doesn't apply to `void*`/`malloc`.

Comment: (+1) I was about to post a similar answer :-) This is a [relevant link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7970036/2633423) on SO.

Comment: `C-style cast should not be used in C++` There should be better justifications than that, or there are none?

Comment: @dmitri: I've updated my answer. Besides, I am a C++ purist.

Comment: Personal preferences are OK but a forum like this is more about technical merits, don't you think? `malloc` returns `void*`, that doesn't carry type information so compiler can't do much of type checking here. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dmitri: Yes, the compiler cannot do much type checking in this case, but **in general** you should use the strictest cast possible, which means `static_cast` would be preferred in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Sticking to the principle to always use the "least-violent" cast, I would recommend `static_cast`.

However, even better would be a wrapper function like

```
template <typename T>
T* mnew(std::size_t count = 1)
{
    return static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T) * count));
}
```

Comment: Why would you use this function, and not just `operator new`?

Comment: Because it (1) returns `NULL` instead of calling the new-handler and/or throwing `std::bad_alloc` in case of errors, (2) the returned pointer must be freed with `free()` instead of `delete[]` or `delete` and (3) it does not call any constructors.

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns void* pointer which you can cast it to any desired pointer using C style casts but C++ introduced 4 new cast operator to overcome one disadvantage assoicated with C style casts and that is they can-not be easily detected using IDE or any other tools like grep.

Conside your example

```
int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof (int));
int *b = static_cast<int *>(malloc(sizeof (int)));
int *c = reinterpret_cast<int *>(malloc(sizeof (int)));
```

Here you can easily search for all instances of static_cast or reinterpret_cast but had it been c style cast            then you got no other way but to simply look or dig into code and spent sleepless nights. Believe me casting bugs are very hard and they undermined strong typing guarantee offered by the C and C++ style languages. But their are some genuine cases where in such cast is needed.

Hence C++ allows C style casting but it intoduce reinterpret_cast operator which does nothing but C style cast operation.

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-ptr