# Array of char* and how to allocate memory for each

Tags: c, malloc

I have a very simple problem that I cannot seem to figure out. I have this:

```
char* array[10];
```

So, I then have 10 `char*` pointers on the stack. Now all I want to do is allocate memory for each pointer. As in:

```
array[0] = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
```

And then store some characters at this location:

```
strncpy(array[0], "hello", sizeof("hello"));
```

Yet, I am getting a compile-time error at the first step of allocating the memory:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

But it works as expected at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/hmIFCB).

What am I doing wrong? I understand what I am *trying* to do, but I do not understand why it does not work. At each index in `array` there is a `char*`. By using the `=` symbol I am trying to assign each pointer to a block of memory allocated to it.

What am I doing wrong? 
Compiling with g++ -g -Wall

Comment: Your question should be tagged c++. g++ is used with c++ files. Your code is working if you try to compile it as pure c code.

Comment: @Igor, What is the difference between using gcc and g++ for this snippet of code?

Comment: G++ is a C++ compiler and C++ compilers demand a cast to convert from `void *` to an `AnythingElse *` (such as `char *`).  C compilers don't demand the cast though they do accept one if it is written as a C style cast.

Comment: C promotes a pointer to the needed type automatically. C++ does not. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) popular question.

Comment: It is at least somewhat tempting to retitle the question along the lines of "Why does a C++ compiler reject code that a C compiler accepts?"

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong? Compiling with g++ -g -Wall

g++ always compile a `.c` file as `.cpp`. Compile it with a C compiler (like GCC). In C++, you must have to cast the return value of `malloc`. In case of C, [do not cast return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2455888).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid C, but you are compiling your code as C++, which, unike C, has no implicit conversion from `void*` to `char*`.

If you intended to compile the code as C (in which case you do not require the cast), use `gcc`, instead of `g++`. Also make sure you your file does not end with an extension that `gcc` interprets as C++ (`.cpp`, `.C`, `.cxx` or `.cc`). Or play it safe and use the `.c` extension.

---

If you want to make the code valid C++, you need to cast to `char*`:

```
array[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*6);
```

Comment: Typically is that not just a warning? I noticed this compile error but I figured since the block was char and not char* then I was miss-understanding something.

Comment: @Igor OP is compiling as C++. Edited the answer.

Comment: @sherrellbc It should be an error. Anyway, `array[0]` is `char*`. Not sure what you mean by "the block".

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most visible difference between C and C++: C can implicitely convert the `void*` returned by `malloc()` to any other type, C++ can't.

Now, by compiling with `g++`, or by using a `.cpp` file name extension, you are compiling your code as C++ code, not C code. Use `gcc` instead and make sure that your source file ends with `.c`, and your code will compile fine.

An alternative solution is to add the cast that C++ requires: `array[0] = static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(char)*6));`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, C++ does not allow an implicit conversion from `void *` to `char *`.

If this is really supposed to be C++ code, I'd advise using `new` instead of `malloc` for dynamic memory allocation, and for this particular code I'd advise using a `vector` of `string` instead of an array of `char *`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
...
std::vector< std::string > array;
...
array[0] = "hello";  // literal is implicitly converted to an instance of string
```

The `string` and `vector` implementations do all the memory management for you.

If this is really supposed to be C code, simply compile it using `gcc` instead of `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
array[0] = static_cast<char *>(malloc(sizeof(char)*6));
```

[How should I cast the result of malloc in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004890/how-should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc-in-c)