# Meaning of "trivial eligible constructor" for implicit lifetime types and memcpy

Tags: c++, lifetime, memcpy

Say you have a type that is trivially copyable, not an aggregate, and not trivially constructible:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;

    Foo(int i)
    : a(i)
    {};

    int a = 5;
};
```

Foo isn't an aggregate because it has a user-declared constructor, it isn't trivially constructible because it has user-defined initialisers, and it is trivially copyable and trivially destructible. It isn't a trivial type.

Is it legal to attempt to implicitly construct such a type via memcpy?

```
Foo* makeFooCopy(const Foo& src)
{
    // Assume alignment isn't a problem
    auto ptr = malloc(sizeof(Foo));

    memcpy(ptr, &src, sizeof(Foo));

    return reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(ptr);
}
```

cppreference says that an implicit lifetime type "...has at least one trivial eligible constructor and a trivial, non-deleted destructor." (the aggregate case does not apply here). But it's not clear to me what the "trivial eligible constructor" is here; must it be a default constructor (i.e. this is just stating that the type needs to be trivially default constructible) or is the ability to trivially copy the object sufficient?

The motivating issue is a vector-like type in our code; profiling shows that in a specific use case a significant amount of our run time consists of copying contiguous containers of trivially copyable but not trivially default constructible types into our vector-like type, which is currently implemented as a loop around emplace_back. We would like to just use memcpy to copy the entire buffer, like so:

```
template<MemcpyableContainer C>
SpecialVectorType(const C& container)
{
    resize(std::size(container));

    memcpy(our_storage, std::addressof(*std::begin(container)), std::size(container) * sizeof(element_type))
}
```

but our compiler isn't optimising out the placement new calls in resize. It's not clear to me if it's legal to elide them.

Comment: OT: You can use `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`; [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19004890/580083).

Comment: _"but our compiler isn't optimising out the placement new calls in resize. It's not clear to me if it's legal to elide them."_ — It seems that the compiler can legally optimize out placement new under the as-if rule. Simple demo: https://godbolt.org/z/eavM7815v. The effect of the default constructor, i.e., the setting of `a` to 5, does not appear in the generated assembly. But I don't think this has anything to do with implicit lifetime types. The optimization happens even before C++20.

Comment: However, when I did the same with multiple objects (as `resize` does as well), the compiler didn't optimized the default constructor away: https://godbolt.org/z/hh331a4ah. So, your problem seem to be related more to compiler optimization capabilities.

Comment: Yeah I did some tests with godbolt and found that Clang would optimise out a single placement new but wouldn't optimise out multiple generated in a loop.

We've already got a mechanism in our resize code to skip doing the placement new for cases where we're about to overwrite the objects anyway; I wanted to know whether it's legal for us to do that or whether it is undefined behaviour. Nimrod's answer confirms that it's legal and we can rely on memcpy implicitly creating objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"At least one trivial eligible constructor" means any of the three constructors(default constructor/copy constructor/move constructor) is trivial.

The type trait [std::is_implicit_lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_implicit_lifetime) is added in C++23.

Here is the implementation in the related draft [p2674](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2674r1.pdf)

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct is_implicit_lifetime
    : std::disjunction<
          std::is_scalar<T>, std::is_array<T>, std::is_aggregate<T>,
          std::conjunction<
              std::is_trivially_destructible<T>,
              std::disjunction<std::is_trivially_default_constructible<T>,
                               std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>,
                               std::is_trivially_move_constructible<T>>>> {};
```

There's no doubt class `Foo` is an *implicit-lifetime type*. It is well defined to implicitly create such objects via `memcpy`.