# Which is more optimal: `new` or `calloc`?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, heap-memory

I use `calloc`, I've read that, `calloc` internally calls `new` handler, so what should I go for?

Should I use `new` operator(which allocate fast) or `calloc`(which can allocate and initialize memory as well)?

Comment: [malloc vs new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new). Use memset if you want to 0 initialize the memory as calloc does.

Comment: calloc (and malloc and realloc) are not allowed to call operator new in C++

Comment: "if you need fast allocation, use `new`; if you need initialized memory, use `calloc`". there is no absolute "optimum" without context.

Comment: `more optimal` doesn't make sense, either something is `optimal` - or not.

Comment: `operator new` is C++ whereas `calloc` is not. Insofar, there's not much to reason which one is more optimal, since only one of them is _correct_.

Comment: @Damon Er, yes, calloc (and even `std::calloc`) is part of C++. Ideally, in cases where they are equivalent, you would just call new and the compiler would optimize that to a call to calloc when appropriate (calloc can be faster than malloc+memset because it sometimes knows the memory is already zero and skips the memset), but in practice that's not the case yet.

Comment: @user1052842: But only memset PODs.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: It is **not** part of C++. It is _mentioned_ in C++ as part of the C standard library (together with some requirements which although they make sense from the PoV of C++ are, frankly, ridiculous, first because the C language doesn't have to care what C++ has to say about its standard library, and second because C++ requires that e.g. `malloc` does not call `operator new` to request memory -- which it certainly doesn't do since there is no such thing as `operator new` in C).

Comment: @Damon Just because `calloc` is also part of C doesn't mean it isn't part of C++ as well. It is a function that is required to be provided by the implementation, like `std::sort`.

Comment: hey @Damon,you please look in to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f8w183e.aspx ,in Remarks item,microsoft people only given such kind of statement, and thanks fa responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, everyone's told you about `new` not initialising memory etc, but they forgot about value-initialization syntax:

```
char *buffer = new char[size]();
```

So I would argue that you *always* use `new`.  If you want to initialise the memory, use the above syntax.  Otherwise, drop the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

The question cannot really be answered, because it's based on the incorrect assumption that `new` merely allocates memory but doesn't initialize it. The contrary is the fact:

`new` not only allocates memory (unless you use "placement new"), it also calls some objects constructor. I.e. `new` does much more than `calloc`.

In C++, if you feel that you need to allocate some memory for e.g. some variable-sized array, consider using the standard containers first, e.g. prefer

```
std::vector<char> buf( 1024 );
```

over

```
char *buf = new char[1024];
```

Answer (score 1):

`calloc` isn't really comparable to `new`; it's closer to `operator new` (they are not the same). `calloc` will zero out the memory allocated whereas `operator new` and `malloc` won't. `new` constructs an object in the storage location but `calloc` doesn't.

```
// Using calloc:
my_object* p = static_cast<my_object*>(std::calloc(1, sizeof(my_object)));
::new(static_cast<void*>(p)) my_object(10);

// Using operator new:
my_object* p = static_cast<my_object*>(::operator new(sizeof(my_object)));
::new(static_cast<void*>(p)) my_object(10);

// using new:
my_object* p = new my_object(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use new operator(which allocate fast) or calloc(which can allocate and initialize memory as well)?

In C++ you should never use *alloc memory function (`malloc`, `calloc`, `free`, etc). They lead you to create code that is unsafe for C++ (for C it is fine).

You should also use most specialized (higher level) code constructs whenever available.

That means:

- prefer `new`/`new[]`/`delete`/`delete[]` over `malloc`/`calloc`/`free`
- prefer smart pointers over raw pointers
- prefer abstractions over raw pointer data (i.e. use `std::vector`/`std::array`/etc instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`, use `std::unique_ptr<T>`/`std::shared_ptr<T>` instead of `T*`, etc.