# Better approach in accessing members of an object from another object c++

Tags: c++, object

I am not really good in c++ so I really need your help. I am using a method inside an object and I would like to access other object members. How can I do that in a better way and not violating OOP?

**This is my .h**

```
class XSection
{
private:    
    char *m_sname;
    XSection *m_snext;
};

class XIniFile
{

private:
    char *m_iname;
    XSection *m_isections;

XSection *addSection(const char *);
}
```

**and I have something like this in .cpp**

```
XSection *XIniFile::addSection(const char *d)
{
    XSection *sn = (XSection *) malloc (sizeof(XSection *));    

    sn->m_sname = strdup(d); 
    return sn;
}
```

I am having an error of `char* XSection::m_sname is private char *m_name;`

How could I use it?

Comment: In order from worst to best: make the member `public`, make the class a `friend` of `XIniFile`, write a setter method, write a constructor. Also, use `new` instead of `malloc`, or better still just return an actual object, not a pointer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new/184540#184540

Comment: Replace the whole thing by `std::list<std::string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is considered bad practice because it violates the concept of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).  In this case, it would be best to give XSection a constructor that sets it up with the desired parameters, and use new instead of malloc.  For example:

The constructor definition:

```
XSection(char* name);
```

Implementation:

```
XSection(char* name) : m_iname(name) { }
```

Usage:

```
XSection* sn = new XSection(strdup(d));
```

But to answer the question directly: if you must, you could make XIniFile a [friend class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class) of XSection:

```
class XSection
{
    friend class XIniFile;
```

Comment: Thank you MrEricSir! I am actually migrating a c program to c++ oop.
----
I really hate it when someone reps me down because of a noob question. I was just asking how I could improve the program.