# Access violation in loading array allocated by malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have an array allocated by `malloc` in the following manner:

```
double * a = ( double * ) malloc( lda * (k+1) * sizeof( double ) );
```

Where `lda=1000` and `k` is a multiple of 40.

Then I try to load the value of `a` in a register in the below stated code

```
reg = _mm_load_pd( (double *) & a[ (p*lda)+0 ]);
```

Where `p` is the index in controlled in the loop.

This code produces access violation error.

I know that to use `_mm_load_pd` the array has to be 16 byte aligned. Doesn't `malloc` already do the alignment? Why then it causes access violation error? Is there anything else I might be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: malloc is only for c, please remove c++ tag

Comment: @Bot: no, you can use `malloc` in C++ too (and there may be cases where this is preferable to `new`, such as when interfacing with certain C code)

Comment: how do you free the allocated data because free function is not allowed because it was replaced with delete function.

Comment: I'm kinda bemused that my question is downvoted! I have seen many people do use malloc in c++!

Comment: look here for more details on why in a contest malloc vs new. New will alway win in C++,                                                                  more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new

Comment: @Bot: what are you talking about? `free` is absolutely allowed; it's part of the standard library. So of course you can `new` and `delete`, or `malloc` and `free`. The former is recommended, but the latter is available for compatibility and for a certain amount of flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` typically only guarantees 8-byte alignment (the alignment of `double`).

If you want 16-byte alignment, you can pad the allocation yourself and adjust the pointers appropriately, or use `posix_memalign`/`_aligned_malloc` depending on your platform to obtain the requisite alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How is alignment done when `new` operator is used for dynamic allocation in c++?

Comment: I think `new` also defaults to 8 bytes, but there I'm not actually sure. You can use `std::aligned_storage` in C++11 to obtain aligned memory, but in C++03 you basically have to do it yourself or use the aforementioned non-standard C aligned-malloc functions.

Comment: "malloc only guarantees 8-byte alignment"  Confident this is wrong.  `malloc()` guarantees `sizeof(max_align_t)` alignment would could be as small as 1.  Whatever it is, it works for the platform.

Comment: @chux: `malloc` has to return a pointer with enough alignment for *any* C object since it is not typechecked. This means that the returned memory **must** be 8-byte aligned, because that's the alignment requirement of `double`.

Comment: Agree that `double` is typically 8-bytes.  That does not require a double must be on an 8-byte aligned address.  Other attributes like bus width contribute to the minimum alignment.

Comment: OK, alignment is implementation-dependent. I updated my answer to say "typically". (This is true on ARM and x86, which covers a pretty significant part of the typical programming targets).

Comment: Not to contradict, but to clarify: Much [x86 memory access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#x86) works with byte access - it is the compiler, not the possessor that provides wider alignment in `malloc()` for performance reasons.  Billions of PIC processors per year in 2014 use 1, 2 or 4 byte alignment and also cover a significant numbers of targets - again it is the _compiler_, with the minimum hardware limit, that provides minimum aliment in `malloc()`.

Comment: Unaligned access on x86 is expensive. Unaligned access on ARM could crash the program. PIC processors usually don't even have floating-point operations, and many are only 8-bit or 16-bit processors anyway. My statement was intended for the typical compilers targeting those platforms.