# Multidimensional Arrays - malloc vs new

Tags: c++, c, arduino, malloc, avr-gcc

I would like to allocate 2D array and I am considering two possibilities (avr-gcc on Arduio):

A:

```
int **arr = new int*[5];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
   arr[i] = new int[10];
}
```

B:

```
 int **arr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));
 for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    arr [i] = malloc(10* sizeof(int))
 }
```

Is there any difference between A and B? Would the compiler create the same byte code in those two cases (arv-gcc)?

Comment: A C compiler won't generate byte code (I hope), but rather it will give you assembly, and ultimately binary.  Did you mean to tag your question with C# or Java?

Comment: Do you know one or both dimensions at compile-time?

Comment: You can see the machine code yourself at gcc.godbolt.org

Comment: If the code you posted is really like the code you're actually using, you should just use static arrays. No need for `new` when the dimensions are known at compile-time.

Comment: dimensions are unknown at compile time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, you can't allocate memory by `new`, because there is no such thing. For C++, you may prefer `new` for couple of reasons such as:

- exceptions (unless you add `(std::nothrow)` explicitly)
- initializer lists (since C++11)
- better safety as it returns pointer of proper type (specifically not `void *`)
- cleaner syntax (but that is purely subjective)

See [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new) for more discussion on that matter.

If you want to allocate a two-dimensional array and the rightmost size is known at compile-time (i.e. it is a constant expression - `constexpr`), then you don't need to loop over.

#### New in C++

```
int (*arr)[10] = new int [2][10];
```

If you want it to be pre-set with zeros (that is, like `std::calloc`), then use:

```
int (*arr)[10] = new int [2][10]{0}; // C++11
int (*arr)[10] = new int [2][10]();  // C++03
```

Just like for any arrays allocated by `new[]`, there is a corresponding `delete[]` operator to free it:

```
delete[] arr;
```

#### Malloc in C and C++

```
int (*arr)[10] = malloc(5 * sizeof(*arr));
```

This allocates array, that is like `arr[5][10]` (only in sense of indices).

To access its elements in both simply use:

```
arr[a][b]
```

To free it, you basically do:

```
free(arr);
```

In C++ you additionally need to take care of cast and possibly qualify it with `std`, so it's `std::malloc` (especially if includes `cstdlib`, as `stdlib.h` header is deprecated in C++ Standard):

```
const int N = 10;

int (*arr)[N] =
    static_cast<int (*)[N]>(std::malloc(5 * sizeof(*arr)));
```

but I don't think that you will like it.

Comment: In C++ you would need to cast malloc, unfortunately

Comment: This example allocates a pointer to a 2D array. This will probably perform better than the OP's example of pointers to pointer since all the memory allocated is together. If you need pointers to pointers you can always construct your pointer array to point into your 2D array.

Comment: this does not work in Arduino Studio . It will throw an error of "Compilation error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int (*)[10]' [-fpermissive]"

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a C++ compiler (and Arduino sketches *are* C++), you should probably prefer `new`. It's unlikely to matter for doing a simple `int` array but I'd leave C legacy stuff only for code that *has* to run in a C environment.

There's absolutely no reason nowadays for C+ programmers (that curious breed of programmer which never whole-heartedly transitions from C to C++) to exist :-)

Comment: Like the C+ programmers tutorial... perhaps you could post a follow-up, explaining why `inline` shouldn't be preferred over macro's that expand to other macro's that expand to some other expression

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, consider it done, feel free to leave a comment (over there rather than here) if it doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: Comment posted, added some example of the type of macro's I've stumbled on in the past

Answer (score 2):

A and B are basically equivalent.

The compiler may or may not create the same code (not byte code BTW). But often using the `new` operator simply boils down to a call to `malloc`. To find out, compile your program with `gcc -S` and have a look at the assembly output.

But for c++ programs you should prefer `new` to `malloc`.