# tbb concurrent hash map as a member of structure

Tags: c++, struct, hashmap, tbb

I want to have a concurrent hash map as a member of structure. I am doing it as below:

```
typedef concurrent_hash_map<int, int> Acreaders;
struct node{ 
    void *obj;  
    int size; // see if required
    Acreaders acrdr;
};
```

So that i should be able to access to insert into the hash table as:

```
Acreaders::accessor a;
struct node *n;
n = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
(n->acrdr).insert(a, 5);
```

Although the program compiles correctly, it leads to segmentation fault.

What might be the problem? Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried writing your code in C++? (I.e. using `new` , as opposed to using C functions such as `malloc`?). For example, currently the constructor of `n->acrdr` will never be called, which is likely the cause of your segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ceedee,

anderas is correct.  mallocing `*n` does not initialize it, but just allocated space for a `node` on the heap.  If you make it:

```
Acreaders::accessor a;
node nn;               // this constructs nn
node *n(&nn);          // point n to nn

(n->acrdr).insert(a, 5);
```

If you want to dynamically allocate `node` specifically using `malloc`, you can initialize it like so:

```
node *n;
n = new(malloc(sizeof(node))) node();  // placement new into space
```

This allocates space on the heap with `malloc`, and constructs node into that space with placement `new`.  In this case you must call the destructor before freeing the space:

```
n->~node();  // destructor frees any additional structures used by node
free(n);
```

Or as anderas described, you can just say

```
n = new node();
```

and after you are done with it, call

```
delete n;
```

You should always use `new` in preference to `malloc` with C++ (and TBB is a C++ library.)  See [In what cases do I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)