# Dereferencing an array of struct pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have declared 2 structs: `point` (which holds 2 doubles) and `circle` (which holds a point and the radius of the circle, a double).

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;   
} point;

typedef struct {
    point m;
    double r;
} circle;
```

To create a circle I use these 2 functions:

```
point* read_point() {
    point* p = malloc (sizeof(point));
    printf("\nx middle:");
    scanf("%lf",&p->x);
    printf("\ny middle:");
    scanf("%lf",&p->y);
    return p;
}

circle* read_circle() {
    circle* c = malloc(sizeof(circle));
    point* p = read_point();
    printf("\nradius circle:");
    scanf("%lf",&c->r);
    c->m = *p;
}
```

In my `main` I declare an array of circle pointers, add one circle and then try to print out the center point and the radius. (At this point my program crashes.)

```
circle* array[3];
array[0] = read_circle();
print_circle(array[0]); //Crashes
```

This is what the print function looks like:

```
void print_circle(circle* c){
    point p = c->m;
    printf("\n%lf",p.x);
    printf("\n%lf",p.y);
    printf("\n%lf",c->r);
}
```

Comment: Craaaaaank up the warnings. `-Wall -Wextra` on GCC and Clang.

Comment: You have a memory leak: You allocate memory for the point, then in `read_circle` you *copy* the `point` structure but never free the memory you allocated for it.

Comment: a memory leak after `point* p = read_point();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read_circle` isn't returning `c` (or anything, for that matter).

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the problem. 2 hours of work for a simple exercise from school and I miss something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check the return value of malloc().

Comment: If I cast using (point*) and (circle*) respectively, is my solution then correct ? (I know I have to free after I use point and circle)

Comment: @Agnaroc [Don't cast the return value of malloc()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

What I ment is to check if malloc() failed (i.e. returned NULL)

Comment: @Mikrosaft: Good advice, but wouldn't solve the current problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter True, but since you already answered it, I didn't feel like I needed to write it again. (It would have made more sense if I commented on his question, but I still can't due to low reputation)

Comment: @Mikrosaft in the school examples malloc is always casted. Why shouldn't it be done here ?

Comment: @Agnaroc Read the link I sent, it gives a few reasons why not to cast.
The only reason I can think of to cast malloc(), is to add compilability between C and C++ (in C++ the cast is mandatory), but since you're writing in C, and since in C++ [you shouldn't use malloc()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new), I see no reason to cast.