# How to build program without cast result of calloc in Xcode?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, casting, calloc

I'm trying to use `calloc` in my program. With an explicit cast it compiles and runs fine, but when I try to [remove the explicit cast of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) I see the following error:

> **Assigning to '... *' (aka '....... *') from incompatible type 'void *'**

How can I compile my code without an explicit cast of `calloc` in Xcode?

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling as C code and not C++? Or perhaps objective-C (which I know nothing about)? C and C++ are distinctly different languages with different casting requirements. If so, please fix up your tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to compile your C code as C++.

While it is true that some C code is also valid in C++, you have come across an example of C code that isn't valid in C++.

That is, C++ does not offer the implicit conversions to/from `void *` that C does.

---

You should **always compile your C code using a C compiler**, for the following three reasons:

- You don't need to compile C code using a C++ compiler.
- You're missing out on the best parts of C++.
- You're missing out on the best parts of C.

---

The only reason people try to compile C code with a C++ compiler is that they anticipate using their C code in a C++ project. However, this is unnecessary because you can usually compile your C code using a C compiler, compile your C++ code using a C++ compiler and then link the two together. For example:

```
gcc -c c_code.c
g++ -c cpp_code.cpp
gcc cpp_library.o c_library.o
```

---

[In C++, it is generally a bad idea to use `*alloc` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new). Those who program specifically in C++ will usually cringe at `*alloc` use.

---

In C, it is always a bad idea to explicitly cast `void *`, as the [link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) explains. Those who program specifically in C will cringe at unnecessary boilerplate that potentially introduces bugs.

Comment: Yes you are correct up voted . I would like know why always compile your C code using a C compiler ?

Comment: @Mohan I edited the answer to add that information. I hope this was helpful :) peace!