# C++ Create Object Array without default constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object, constructor

I get an error when dynamically creating an array of a (transaction) object. The error output says:"no matching function for call to 'Transaction::Transaction()'
This is part of an assignment and we are not allowed to use a default constructor. From what I gather an array automatically assigns values to each of its indexed address when it's created and as no default constructor is made for Transaction, it cannot do this without values. Please help me see what I could do to fix this error.

```
class Transaction
{
private:
  int id;
  float amount;
  string fromAddress, toAddress, signature;
  bool confirmed, removeFromPool;
  static int numTransactions;


public:
  Transaction(string in_fA, string in_tA,string in_sign,float in_amount);
  Transaction(Transaction &obj);
  int getId() const;
}
//---------------------

class Block
{
private:
  int id, txCount;
  const int MAX_TX=5;
  Transaction** txList;
  string blockHash, prevBlockHash, minerName;
  bool confirmed;

public:
  Block(int id,string prevH,string name);
  }
//------------------
// block.cpp
Block::Block(int i, string prevH, string name)
{
*txList = new Transaction[MAX_TX];
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` and `push_back`/`emplace_back`.

Comment: If you want to still use pointers and want to initialize all objects to the same value, then you can do e.g. `*txList = new Transaction[MAX_TX](parameters_passed_to_all_constructors)`

Comment: Define default constructor?

Comment: BTW, currently, `txList` is not initialized, you probably want something like `txList = new Transaction*[MAX_TX]; for (int i = 0; i != MAX_TX; ++i) { txList[i] = new Transaction(/*parameters*/); }`

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using a plain dynamic array, you *could* do this:

```
*txList = new Transaction[MAX_TX]{{"1", "2", "3", 4},
                                  // 3 more
                                  {"5", "6", "7", 8}};
```

---

But instead you could declare your constructor as:

```
Transaction(string in_fA = "a", string in_tA = "b", string in_sign = "c", float in_amount = 42);
```

And thus attempt to dodge the silly 'no default ctor' requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `std::vector` is the easiest (and best) way to deal with this:

```
class Block {
public:
  Block()
    : txList(MAX_TX, Transaction("a", "b", "C", 0.0f)) {}

private:
  std::vector<Transaction> txList;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your "assignment" and you are not allowed to use default constructors I assume you are expected to use one of these:

- `malloc`
- `std::vector` which uses `malloc` under the hood

In *the first* option memory allocation looks like this:

```
Transaction* transactionsList = (Transaction*) malloc(size * sizeof(Transaction));
```

**Edit**: don't forget that after `malloc` you use `free` and **not** `delete` to free the memory.

I have to note, that the usage of `malloc` is usually discouraged in favor of `new` in C++. The point of `new` is to merge together 2 phases: memory allocation and memory initialization (+ the pointer type conversation is done for you). However, everything you need is to allocate a chunk of memory, you may consider malloc. Anyway, [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new).

*The second* option which **Jarod42** and **Frank** noted:

```
std::vector<Transaction> transactionsList(size, *default_value*);
```

and you get the vector of `size` elements, each is initialized to the default value you specified.

If you are allowed to define a move `Transaction(Transaction&& obj) = default;` or a copy constructor `Transaction(const Transaction& obj) { ... }`, you also can also reserve memory:

```
std::vector<Transaction> transactionsList;
transactionsList.reserve(size);
```

and then add a new element with `emplace_back()` or `push_back()`.