# How to get data into overloaded constructor using an array of objects?

Tags: c++

Basically my question is how to get data into overloaded constructor with an array of objects, i first read the data in from the textile and then want to set those values with overloaded constructor but how do i do that an array of objects my code is below i know that normally without the array it would be song group member(number of parameters); my code is below

```
#include <iostream>// Program By Richard Okpala 1/30/2018
#include <string>// libaries used for program
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#include "song.h"
int main() {
    ifstream myfile;
    ofstream outfile;
    string first_name, last_name, Artist_name, song_name, song_duration, given_genre;//variables used to get data into class
    song GroupMember[35];
    /*song GroupMember1, GroupMember2, GroupMember3, GroupMember4, GroupMember5, GroupMember6, GroupMember7, GroupMember8, GroupMember9, gorupMember10
        , GroupMember11, GroupMember12, GroupMember13, GroupMember14, GroupMember15, GroupMember16, GroupMember17, GroupMember18, GroupMember19, GroupMember20, GroupMember21, GroupMember22

    , GroupMember23, GroupMember24, GroupMember25, GroupMember26, GroupMember27, GroupMember28, GroupMember29, GroupMember30, GroupMember31, GroupMember32, GroupMember33, GroupMember34, GroupMember25;*/
    myfile.open("myfile.txt");
    outfile.open("class.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open the file" << endl;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    while (!myfile.eof()) {
        getline(myfile, first_name, '\t');
        getline(myfile, last_name, '\t');
        getline(myfile, Artist_name, '\t');
        getline(myfile, song_name, '\t');
        getline(myfile, song_duration, '\t');
        getline(myfile, given_genre, '\t');
    }
    myfile.close();
}
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "song.h"
song::song(string given_first, string given_last, string given_artist, string given_song, string given_duration, string given_genre)
{
    the_first = given_first;
    the_last = given_last;
    the_artist = given_artist;
    the_song = given_song;
    the_durartion = given_duration;
    the_genre = given_genre;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Re eof: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: have you heard of phrases? plural?

Comment: why will it be out of bounds after 20 songs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Create Object Array without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680562/c-create-object-array-without-default-constructor)