# initialize an empty unordered_map inside my structure in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `std::unordered_map<char, Node*>` inside my custom structure. 
I want to initialize it with an empty `map`. Did I do something wrong?
I have tried 2 kinds of initialization, both of them give me same result.

The following statement:

```
newStructure->map = unordered_map<char, Node*>();
```

sometimes results in success and the size of this map is 0, which it should be. Most of the time, this would fail during the initialization, and the following error would be generated with no initialization of the `map`:

> malloc: pointer being freed was not allocated

This would give me extreme huge size of the initial `std::unordered_map`. The size of the map could be `88029716824088`.

How can I correctly initialize an empty `std::unordered_map` struct?

My structure is defined like this:

```
struct Node {
    char letter;
    unordered_map<char, Node*> next;
    bool hasEnd;
    static Node* init(char);
}
```

And, my `initializer` is defined like this:

```
Node* Node::init(char letter) {
    Node *newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->letter = letter;
    newNode->hasEnd = false;
    return newNode;
};
```

Sometimes, the size of the `next` would be very huge number.

Comment: if u define a map it is already empty.

Comment: @user1438832 but the size of the map could sometimes go very large. How could that possible?

Comment: You are not using `malloc` to allocate C++ objects, are you? [In what cases should I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)

Comment: @BoPersson, thank you so much. I just come from C, and I'm not very familiar with the detail of the C++. The map work normal now. I think I need to find out the difference between `new` and `malloc` now.

Comment: @Judgelight - It's rather simple really. Don't use `malloc` and you'll be fine. If you wonder "but what if I need to use `malloc`?" then you'll have to wait a long time until you have a real need. And by then you'll know enough C++ to use it wisely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `new` instead of `malloc` when creating C++ objects.

When you create a map it is already empty by default.

You can read more here: [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)

Answer (score 0):

The actual failure and the strange map size happens because when you do this:

```
Node *newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

You are saying that there `struct Node` at the address you got from `malloc`.

The problem is that the constructor for the `unordered_map` will not get called. And `malloc` is not required to return zeroed memory.

This means that internals of `unordered_map` will simply be whatever values are there in the memory returned by `malloc`. Also keep in mind that zeroes also might not be ok for correct initialization of `unordered_map` internals. It will only be correctly initialized if its constructor gets called.
This you a Node with a broken `unordered_map` member

Then when you do:

```
newStructure->map = unordered_map<char, Node*>();
```

The destructor for the `unordered_map` will get called, because you are actually replacing the `unordered_map` which you said is already there with a new one. Since the values in the memory you got from `malloc` might not be 0 and the `unordered_map` internals might contain a pointer to some memory that gets allocated when its constructor gets called, the destructor will try to deallocate some random value, causing the error you are seeing.