# C++ Structure error at Return 0?

Tags: c++, struct

Fairly new, the code output is as follows:

1->2->exit

However, program fails to execute completely, (even though this is the end of program, spooky)

Here is the code:

```
struct ListN{
int value;
ListN* next;
};

int main()
{
struct ListN* newn = (struct ListN*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListN));
newn->value = 1;

struct ListN* temp;
temp = newn;

newn= newn->next;

newn->value = 2;
newn->next = NULL;

while(temp!=NULL){
    printf("%d ->",temp->value);
    temp = temp->next;
}
printf("exit");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you're really programming C++? You only use *one* C++-specific feature (unless there's a `typedef` you don't show us), and you use it only *once* even though you could do it in multiple places.

Comment: As for your problem, `newn= newn->next;` is probably not what you want to do, and will lead to *undefined behavior* in the very next statement.

Comment: `malloc`? You claim it’s C++!

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstdlib/malloc

This link showed malloc in C++ also, and this answered why i shouldnt use malloc 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new

Thanks, learned

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to the following sequence:

```
struct ListN* newn = (struct ListN*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListN));
newn->value = 1;
newn= newn->next;
newn->value = 2;
```

The first two statements create a new element and set its data value but do *not* set its "next element" pointer to anything.

The third statement sets `newn` to the arbitrary value stored in the `next` pointer of the first element, and the fourth dereferences that to try and set its value.

This (dereferencing an arbitrary pointer) is undefined behaviour, pure and simple. At that point, literally *anything* is allowed to happen.

If you're looking to construct a two-element list, the following is a more correct way to do it:

```
struct ListN* newn = (struct ListN*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListN));
newn->value = 1;
newn->next = (struct ListN*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListN));

newn= newn->next;
newn->value = 2;
newn->next = NULL;
```

Though you should really take into account:

- that you would be better off using `new` rather than `malloc` in C++;
- that, if you *do* use `malloc`, you should check for failure; and
- C++ (from C++11 onwards) already *has* a singly-linked list in its repertoire, `forward_list`. You should probably just use *that* unless your intent is to learn algorithms. Before C++11, you could just use `list`, though this is a doubly-linked list.

Comment: Thank you!.. Coming back to C/C++ after a very long time, thus some basic concept flaws. Your answer helps thanks