# Creating BST from sorted array in C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Can you help me understand why this code randomly results in memory access violation? Goal is to generate a binary search tree from sorted list.

Stepping through code I noticed a behavior where `node` pointer randomly changes when a recursive calls to `fromSortedArray()` function  is returned. To give you a contex I am compiling this app using XCODE.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class BST{
private:
    struct Node {
        int val;
        struct Node *left, *right;
    } *root;

public:
    BST(){
        this->root = NULL;
    }

    struct Node * fromSortedArray(int data[], int left, int right){
        if(left>right) return NULL;
        int m = left+(right -left)/2;
        struct Node *node = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
        node->val = data[m];
        node->left = this->fromSortedArray(data, left, m-1);
        node->right = this->fromSortedArray(data, m+1, right);
        return node;
    }

    void fromSortedArray(int data[], int n){
        this->root = fromSortedArray(data, 0, n-1);
    }

    void deleteTree(struct Node *root){
        if(root==NULL) return;
        deleteTree(root->left);
        deleteTree(root->right);
        delete root;
    }

    void deleteTree(){
        this->deleteTree(this->root);
    }

    void traverse(struct Node *root){
        if(root == NULL) return;
        if(root->left!=NULL)traverse(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->val);
        if(root->right!=NULL)traverse(root->right);
    }
    void traverse(){
        this->traverse(this->root);
    }

    ~BST(){
        deleteTree();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    BST tree;
    int data[] = {2,3,5,6,7,9};
    tree.fromSortedArray(data, 6);
    tree.traverse();
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Node`s are being `malloc`ed. One cannot combine `malloc` and `delete`. `malloc` must be matched with `free` and `new` must be matched with `delete`.

Avoid `malloc`. It gets you bytes of memory and nothing more, and you can easily miscalculate the number of bytes required. `malloc` should only be used in C++ in rare edge cases. More reading on the topic: [In what cases do I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)

Use `new` instead of `malloc` and if at all possible, don't use `new` either. Use an Automatic variable, a library container, or a smart pointer instead.

This is a tree structure and, opinion here, so long as you observe the [Rules of Three and Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) you can get away with raw, stupid pointers because it's the the tree structure's job to handle the management of the nodes. That said, play around a bit with `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` when you get a chance. They can make your life easier.

Sticking with raw pointers for now, replace

```
struct Node *node = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
```

with

```
Node *node = new Node;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this line is wrong.
 struct Node *node = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));

should be
  sizeof(struct Node) becacuse you want to apply memory for Node not Node*

Comment: Thank you for the answer that helped to figure out the bug.