# How to make return type of a function to be same as another function?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

there is a question in our study book about object functions. There is a code in c++ and the question wants us to fill the blanks. The code is as below

```
template <typename Arg, typename Ret> 
class FuncObj {
public:
    typedef Arg argType;
    typedef Ret retType;
    virtual Ret operator()(Arg) = 0;
};

class DivideBy : public FuncObj<int, double> {
protected:
    int divisor;
public:
    DivideBy(int d) {
        this->divisor = d;
    }
    double operator()(int x) {
        return x/((double)divisor);
    }
};

class Truncate : public FuncObj<double, int> {
public:
    int operator()(double x) {
        return (int) x;
    }
};

template < typename Ftype , typename Gtype >
class Compose : public FuncObj <typename Gtype :: argType, typename Ftype :: retType > {
protected:
    Ftype *f; Gtype *g;
public:
    Compose(Ftype f,Gtype g) {
    --------- =f;
    --------- =g; 
    }

    ---------- operator()(____________x) {
        return (_________)((________)(__________)); }
};
```

The desirable result is

```
void main() {
    DivideBy *d = new DivideBy(2);
    Truncate *t = new Truncate();
    Compose<DivideBy, Truncate> *c1 = new Compose<DivideBy,Truncate>(d,t);
    Compose<Truncate, DivideBy> *c2 = new Compose<Truncate, DivideBy>(t,d);
    cout << (*c1)(100.7) << endl; // Prints 50.0 
    cout << (*c2)(11) << endl; // Prints 5
}
```

I really don't know how to complete this code, so what feature or concept of c++ should we use to make this work? If there is a link for further study about this topic please write it down.
thanks.

Comment: this->f = &f; this->g = &g; ?

Comment: Your study book is not worth the paper its printed on, honestly. The author didn't even bother verifying this non-trivial code is free of errors.

Comment: On a side note: Remove all `new` and `*`, these are unneeded and cause memory leaks as you don't delete them. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/184537/2466431 for more details

Comment: The code is *very* bad! The author of the book did not know how a constructor work! Overwriting in body of constructor instead of using initialization in the initializer list is more or less a failure. Maybe the types are not default constructible and all the code brakes. Where can we find the "delete" for all the unneeded "new"? Please take a better book and tell your teacher that this code quality can never be used for production!

Answer (score 5):

This code is awful (and so is the study book if that's the average quality of the material).

First, `void main()` is not a valid signature for `main`. It should be `int main()` in this case. Second, if `Compose` is supposed to be constructed with pointers, then its constructor should be declared as `Compose(Ftype* f, Gtype* g)`, not `Compose(Ftype f, Gtype g)`. Third, the code should include `<iostream>` and prefix `cout` and `endl` with `std::` (or use `using namespace std`, but that would still be pretty bad). Finally, all `new` should have a corresponding `delete`, but even better would be using smart pointers, or no pointer at all.

Anyway, after all of that, filling in the blanks is relatively simple.
The constructor would be written like this:

```
Compose(Ftype f,Gtype g) {
    this->f = f;
    this->g = g;
}
```

...which is pretty bad because it forces the use of `this->` when it's unnecessary (either name the parameters differently, or use the member initializer list).
And the call operator would be written like so:

```
typename Ftype::retType operator()(typename Gtype::argType x) {
    return (*f)((*g)(x));
}
```

The argument type and return type are those passed to the base class `FuncObj` as template arguments, and then the call simply composes `f` and `g`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8b706385d112db1).

A better code without using any pointer would look like this:

```
template<typename Ftype, typename Gtype>
class Compose : public FuncObj<typename Gtype::argType, typename Ftype::retType> {
protected:
    Ftype f;
    Gtype g;
public:
    Compose(Ftype f, Gtype g)
    : f(f), g(g) {
    }

    typename Ftype::retType operator()(typename Gtype::argType x) {
        return f(g(x));
    }
};

int main() {
    auto d = DivideBy(2);
    auto t = Truncate();
    auto c1 = Compose(d, t);
    auto c2 = Compose(t, d);
    std::cout << c1(100.7) << "\n";
    std::cout << c2(11) << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de2bf4bc70341bea).

Instead of using the Java-like initializations `Type *var = new Type(args);`, just use value (`auto var = Type(args);` or `Type var(args)`). C++ is not Java.
Note that you don't even need to specify the template arguments to `Compose`: they are deduced from the constructor arguments.

Comment: @paulsm4 Most of the time auto is optional. But sometimes you really don't know the type and auto is necessary, `auto f = []() { ... };`

Comment: @paulsm4 That's another debate. `auto` is one of the things I really *like* about modern C++. And I have arguments for it. I don't mind if you dislike using `auto` and similar things in other languages, but that's not really the point here.

Answer (score 0):

Filling the blank is not very difficult but I want to say the code style is really terrible.

```
template <typename Ftype, typename Gtype>
class Compose : public FuncObj<typename Gtype ::argType, typename Ftype ::retType>
{
  protected:
    Ftype *f;
    Gtype *g;

  public:
    Compose(Ftype *f, Gtype *g) : f(f), g(g){}; // Prefer constructor initialization list.

    typename Ftype ::retType operator()(typename Gtype ::argType arg)
    {
        return (*f)((*g)(arg));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto *d = new DivideBy(2);
    auto *t = new Truncate();
    auto *c1 = new Compose<DivideBy, Truncate>(d, t);
    auto *c2 = new Compose<Truncate, DivideBy>(t, d);
    cout << (*c1)(100.7) << endl;
    cout << (*c2)(11) << endl;
    delete d;
    d = nullptr;
    delete t;
    t = nullptr;
    delete c1;
    c1 = nullptr;
    delete c2;
    c2 = nullptr; // You need to be very careful with bare pointers.Use unique_ptr and shared_ptr in modern C++.
}
```