# How to share a common resource between two threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Here is my piece of code, where I am trying to access a resource in two different  threads in a detach mode, but I am not able read the update value of m_dataLoaded in second thread. It continues to wait even if the condition is met. I don't understand the logic behind this and how can I achieve this??

Header file
application.h

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_H
#define APPLICATION_H

#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class Application
{
public:
    Application();

    bool isDataLoaded();

    void loadData();

    void mainTask();

private:
    bool m_dataLoaded;
    std::condition_variable m_condVar;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

#endif // APPLICATION_H
```

Source file
application.cpp

```
#include "application.h"

Application::Application()
           : m_dataLoaded(false)
{
}

bool Application::isDataLoaded()
{
     return m_dataLoaded;
}

void Application::loadData()
{
    std::cout << "Inside loadData" << std::endl;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(m_mutex);

    while(true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

        m_dataLoaded = true;

        if(m_dataLoaded)
        {
            m_condVar.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

void Application::mainTask()
{
    std::cout << "Inside mainTask" << std::endl;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> u_lock(m_mutex);

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;

        m_condVar.wait(u_lock, std::bind(&Application::isDataLoaded, this));

        std::cout << "Start Data Processing: " << std::endl;

        m_dataLoaded = false;
    }

    std::cout << "Break out of the loop" << std::endl;
}
```

main file
main.cpp

```
#include "application.h"

int main()
{
    Application *app = new Application;

    std::thread *thread_1 = new std::thread(&Application::mainTask, app);
    std::thread *thread_2 = new std::thread(&Application::loadData, app);

    thread_2->detach();
    thread_1->detach();

    while(1)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For above piece of code thread_1 keeps on waiting...
I don't understand why this happens.
Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: ... your application ends before you can see any results. Threads were started, detach was called, so `main` ends immediately.

Comment: thank you @rafix07, you were right. I put a infinite loop at the end of main and I can see the print statements

Comment: `std::thread::join` iso detach would make more sense. Why do you [new all classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53898150/2466431)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And was called out by rafix07 in the comments section of your question - `main` is likely exiting and triggering program termination before either thread has a chance to do anything.  But that's not your only bug.

You are forgetting to break out of the loop in `mainTask`.  Your code in mainTask is stuck in a `while(true)` loop - even after `isDataLoaded()` becomes a true expression.

```
while (true) // <<=== INFINITE LOOP
{
    std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;

    m_condVar.wait(u_lock, std::bind(&Application::isDataLoaded, this));

    std::cout << "Start Data Processing: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

}
```

Traditional "loop" approach that I prefer because it resembles the pthreads pattern of checking the condition first, then waiting, and then checking again (because of spurious wakeups).

```
while (!isDataLoaded())
{
    std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;

    m_condVar.wait(u_lock);
}

std::cout << "Start Data Processing: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
```

Or without using a loop, just use the predicate approach without an explicit loop:

```
std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;

m_condVar.wait(u_lock, [this]() {
    return isDataLoaded();
});

std::cout << "Start Data Processing: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
```

---

Here's your comlete program modified with corrections:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>


class Application
{
public:
    Application();

    bool isDataLoaded();

    void loadData();

    void mainTask();

private:
    bool m_dataLoaded;
    std::condition_variable m_condVar;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

Application::Application()
    : m_dataLoaded(false)
{
}

bool Application::isDataLoaded()
{
    return m_dataLoaded;
}

void Application::loadData()
{
    std::cout << "Inside loadData" << std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(m_mutex);

    m_dataLoaded = true;

    m_condVar.notify_all();
}

void Application::mainTask()
{
    std::cout << "Inside mainTask" << std::endl;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> u_lock(m_mutex);

    while (!isDataLoaded())
    {
        std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;

        m_condVar.wait(u_lock);
    }

    std::cout << "Done Waiting" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Application *app = new Application;

    std::thread *thread_1 = new std::thread(&Application::mainTask, app);
    std::thread *thread_2 = new std::thread(&Application::loadData, app);

    std::cout << "Thread_1 id: " << thread_1->get_id() << std::endl;

    thread_2->detach();
    thread_1->detach();

    while (true)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100000));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I have edited my code and I think I have entered into a deadlock. But I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: Perhaps that `while(1) {}` loop you have in the main thread is starving the threads. I've appended the complete program with my updates.  Works for me.