# Deque implementation using doubly linked listed

Tags: c++

So I have to implement deque using doubly linked list and am supposed to put objects of class Students but I keep getting a sedimentation error. 
I am basically trying to put data into the object before pushing it.
please help as it would mean a lot to me

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct Students
{
    string name;
    int snum;
    void getdata()
    {
        cout<<"Enter name of student:  ";
    getline(cin,name);
        cout<<"\nEnter Student number: ";;
        cin>>snum;
    }
    void showdata()
    {
        cout<<"Name: "<<name;
        cout<<"\nStudent Number: "<<snum<<"\n";
    }
};

struct node
{
    Students s;
    node *prev, *next;

    static node* getnode(Students s)
    {
    node* newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(Students));
    newnode->s = s;
    newnode->prev = newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
    }
};


class deque
{
    node* front;
    node* rear;
    int Count;

public:
    deque()
    {
    front = rear = NULL;
    Count = 0;
    }


    void pushFront(Students s);
    void pushBack(Students s);
    void popFront();
    void popBack();
    Students peekFront();
    Students peekBack();
    int count();
    bool isEmpty();
    void clear();
};


bool deque::isEmpty()
{
return (front == NULL);
}


int deque::count()
{
return Count;
}


void deque::pushFront(Students s)
{
node* newnode = node::getnode(s);

if (newnode == NULL)
cout << "OverFlow\n";
else
{

if (front == NULL)
rear = front = newnode;

//puts node at front
else
{
newnode->next = front;
front->prev = newnode;
front = newnode;
}

// increase by 1
Count++;
}
}


void deque::pushBack(Students s)
{
node* newnode = node::getnode(s);


if (newnode == NULL)
cout << "OverFlow\n";
else
{

if (rear == NULL)
front = rear = newnode;


else
{
    newnode->prev = rear;
    rear->next = newnode;
    rear = newnode;
    }

    Count++;
    }
    }


void deque::popFront()
{

if (isEmpty())
cout << "UnderFlow\n";


else
{
node* temp = front;
front = front->next;


if (front == NULL)
rear = NULL;
else
front->prev = NULL;
free(temp);


Count--;
}
}


void deque::popBack()
{

if (isEmpty())
cout << "UnderFlow\n";


else
{
node* temp = rear;
rear = rear->prev;


if (rear == NULL)
front = NULL;
else
rear->next = NULL;
free(temp);


Count--;
}
}


Students deque::peekFront()
{

if (isEmpty())
    abort() ;

return front->s;
// s.showdata();
}


Students deque::peekBack()
{

if (isEmpty())
    abort();

return rear->s;
}


void deque::clear()
{
rear = NULL;
while (front != NULL)
{
node* temp = front;
front = front->next;
free(temp);
}
Count = 0;
}

// main
int main()
{

deque dq;
Students s1,s2,s3,s4;
s1.getdata();
dq.pushBack(s1);
s2.getdata();
dq.pushBack(s2);
s3.getdata();
dq.pushBack(s3);
s4.getdata();
dq.pushBack(s4);


return 0;
}
```

I am pretty sure the problem lies in getnode() at the start but I am not entirely sure

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried to use a debugger? This is exactly why we have them. Anyway, short answer: _never use `malloc` and `free` in C++_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new)