# Can not read the string variable in linked list

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list that will store words and how many times they occurred in the .txt file. Before reading I'm trying to create a linked list to see if it is okay. While testing, it is crashing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
struct n {

    std::string word;
    int occurance;
    n* next;
};

typedef n node;

int main() {
    node* root;
    root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
    
    root->word = "test";
    root->occurance = 5;

    std::cout << root->word
        << root->occurance << std::endl;
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLEpO.png)

Comment: `typedef n node;` -- Totally unnecessary, and error-prone.  Why did you need to do this?  Second, what C++ book introduces using `malloc` to create a dynamically allocated object?  That is wrong in this context

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++ when you have `new`?

Comment: `root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));` Your sizeof is a pointer. You want  `sizeof(node)`

Comment: `root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));` -- This does not construct `node` objects, but your code assumes it did.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp True, but even better to not bother with `malloc` at all, because it doesn't initialize anything.

Comment: If you want a linked list in C++, use `std::list` .  Rolling your own is literally pointless. At a bare minimum you should understand that all `malloc` does is allocate dynamic memory. That object class (`n`), is non-trivial. It has a member `word` that requires non-trivial construction, therefore so too goes `n`. Therefore, `node *root = new node;` would be appropriate, as `operator new` invokes construction,

Answer (score 1):

```
root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

Is wrong in two ways. You should use

```
root = new node;
```

Firstly you code will allocate space for a `node*` (usually 4 or 8 bytes) not for a `node`.

Secondly `malloc` only allocates memory, but doesn't initialize it. See also [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new)<sup>1</sup> That means all members of the newly allocated `node` have indeterminate values and reading them will cause undefined behaviour.
In your case this manifests as access vioaltion.

---

<sup>1</sup> In modern C++ you should avoid both ;)

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` is a holdover from C, which is how C developed back in the previous century. It compiles, but that's mostly bad luck.

Just move to at least 1998, and use `std::list`, or perhaps `std::map<std::string, int>`. Explaining why obsolete technology fails isn't that useful.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(node*)` gets the size of a pointer to a `node`. Probably 4 or 8 bytes. `malloc(sizeof(node*))` allocates that many bytes.

But a `node` is bigger than a pointer to a `node`. So then your code fills in all the data and goes past the end of the memory it allocated because it only allocated enough space for a pointer.

Solution 1: change `malloc(sizeof(node*))` to `malloc(sizeof(node))`

Solution 2: change `(node*)malloc(sizeof(node*))` to `new node` because it's C++ (not C) and you can do that.

Also, don't forget to free it (`free(root);` for `malloc` or `delete node;` for `new`). The OS automatically frees all your stuff when the program ends, so it's not important in this short program, but when you make a program that does a lot of stuff, you have to free the memory from one part so that the next part can reuse it.

Comment: The other issue is that `node` is not a trivial type, thus `malloc` is a non-starter.