# How do you create a POINT object in Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to use the `PtInRect` function in Win32, which takes a `POINT` object. I have x and y coordinates, but I don't know how I create a `POINT` from those. I tried looking it up, but could only find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-point) documentation, which does not contain the information I want.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Its a struct, so its created the same way as any other struct.

Comment: @tkausl I suppose I could just do `POINT pt = (POINT*)malloc(sizeof(POINT));` and then set the x and y, but I was wondering if there a a function to do this (like `CreateWindow` for windows)

Comment: are you using C++ or C? Because your question is tagged C++ and your comment is using C.

Comment: `POINT pt {10,20};` would be a  `c++` example. I would avoid `malloc` in `c++` code however the problem with your example is POINT is not a pointer. `PPOINT` is.

Comment: Allocated on the stack: `POINT pt{10,20};`, allocate on the heap: `auto pt{ new POINT{10,20} };`

Comment: POINT is not an *object*, it's simply a structure.

Comment: @drescherjm That was a typo, and why shouldn't I use `malloc`?

Comment: This question should explain that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new)

Comment: @drescherjm thanks! So if I wanted to allocate memory for it, then I should use `new` anyway.

Comment: It's unreasonable to assume that you can access a C API proficiently when you don't understand the basics of C. Things were better around here back when we enforced the requirement that askers of questions demonstrated basic familiarity with the problem domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem:**

You're creating trouble for yourself because of attempting to dynamically allocate the `POINT` object with `malloc`. BTW you do not always need dynamic allocation and to initialize any struct you do not need to use `malloc` as you pointed in the comments, you can just create the object directly.

**Solution:**

As `tkausl` pointed in the comments, `POINT` is created in the same way as any other struct.

Some examples on how creating a `POINT`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int someX = 100;
    int someY = 100;
    RECT testRect1 = {0,0,200,200};
    RECT testRect2 = {150,150,350,350};
    POINT p1{someX,someY};
    POINT p2 = {someX,someY};
    POINT p3;
    p3.x = someX;
    p3.y = someY;
    std::cout << (bool) PtInRect(&testRect1,p1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (bool) PtInRect(&testRect1,p2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (bool) PtInRect(&testRect1,p3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (bool) PtInRect(&testRect1,{someX,someY}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (bool) PtInRect(&testRect2,p1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (bool) PtInRect(&testRect2,p2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (bool) PtInRect(&testRect2,p3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (bool) PtInRect(&testRect2,{someX,someY}) << std::endl;
}
```