# Can someone explain why this error appears?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

This warnings appear:

```
f.c:14:16: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [2]' [-Wint-conversion]
    head1 -> data = "K";
                  ^ ~~~

f.c:16:16: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char [2]' [-Wint-conversion]
    head2 -> data = "a";
                  ^ ~~~
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
        char data;
        struct _node *link;
}node;

int main (){
        node *head1 = NULL;
        node *head2 = NULL;
        head1 = (node *)malloc (sizeof (node));
        head2 = (node *)malloc (sizeof (node));
        head1 -> data = "K";
        head1 -> link = head2;
        head2 -> data = "a";

        printf("%c%c", head1->data, head2->data);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `head1 -> data = "K";` to `head1 -> data = 'K';`

Comment: @RichardCritten It looks like it is the usual "Let's also tag it C++ to get more answers" problem. The file name from the error message is `f.c`, so it seems to be a C question.

Comment: Do you run your code through a C++ compiler? Otherwise please don't tag C++ language.

Answer (score 1):

The below answer assumes you want a C++ specific answer.

The [problem](https://onlinegdb.com/sWJJ5ebNJ) is that `"K"` has type `const char[2]`. And when you wrote

```
head1 -> data = "K";
```

the right hand side **decays** to `const char*`. But note the left hand side is still a `char`. So as the error says, you can't convert `const char*` to `char`.

Similarly, `"a"` has type `const char[2]`. And when you wrote

```
head2 -> data = "a";
```

the right hand side **decays** to `const char*` but the left hand side is still `char`. And since we cannot convert a `const char*` to `char`, you get the mentioned error.

You can **solve** this by replacing `head1 -> data = "K";` and `head2 -> data = "a";` with:

```
head1 -> data = 'K'; //note single quote around K
head2 -> data = 'a'; //note single quote around a
```

**Mistake 2**

**Instead** of using `malloc` and then dereferencing `head1` the way you did, you should use `new` like:

```
node *head1 = new node;
node *head2 = new node;
```

Also don't forget to use `delete` the allocated memory on heap. So the modified program looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
typedef struct _node {
        char data;
        struct _node *link;
}node;

int main (){
        node *head1 = new node;
        node *head2 = new node;
      
        head1 -> data = 'K';
        head1 -> link = head2;
        head2 -> data = 'a';
        std::cout<<head1->data<<" "<<head2->data;
        
        //DONT FORGET TO DELETE 
        delete head1;
        delete head2;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: At no point does the `char[2]` array decay to a pointer; it remains an rvalue with type `char[2]`. Removing the incorrect information about decay and the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a `char` variable, use simple brackets: `' '`

`head1 -> data = "K";` -> wrong

`head1 -> data = 'K';` -> OK

Also use new instead of malloc, never use malloc for almost anything:

WRONG:

```
head1 = (node *)malloc (sizeof (node));
head2 = (node *)malloc (sizeof (node));
```

OK:

```
head1 = new Node;
head2 = new Node;
```

Comment: why I can not use malloc? can I use malloc to store integers?

Comment: @Kamol Basically because malloc comes from C, not C++ , so it has some deficiencies. Even if you can use `malloc` with C ++, new is better. If you want more details, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/184537/17308658

Comment: @Kamol I've just realised that it's a C program, and you tagged C++. Don't do that to get more answers. Anyway, what I said about `new` only applies to C ++.