# libiconv - cannot convert argument 2 from 'char **' to 'const char **'

Tags: c++, iconv, libiconv

I am trying to use libxml2 with libiconv to parse xml files. Now I faced encoding conversion issue.

here is my function:

```
char* convert_iconv(char* in)
{
    char* out;
    size_t size, out_size;

    size = strlen(in) + 1;
    out_size = size * 2 - 1;
    out = (char*)malloc(out_size);

    iconv_t ic = iconv_open("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8");
    iconv(ic, &in, &size, &out, &out_size);
    iconv_close(ic);

    
    return (out);
}
```

function `iconv(ic, &in, &size, &out, &out_size)` gives an error:

> cannot convert argument 2 from 'char **' to 'const char **'

okay, that function really needs const char **

```
//size_t iconv(iconv_t cd, const char** inbuf, size_t * inbytesleft, char** outbuf, size_t * outbytesleft);
```

**But** any attempts to pass const char ** as an argument fail. First error **still occurs**, and another error appears:

> argument of type "const char **" is incompatible with parameter of
> type "char **"

Changing

```
char* convert_iconv(char* in)
```

to

```
char* convert_iconv(const char* in)
```

doesn't help

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: I see that `iconv` takes `char **` for both parameters.

Comment: my program is c++, but library is implemented in C https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2

Comment: What does "any attempts to pass const char **" mean? Show the code, don't describe it.

Comment: The `in` parameter for the function should be `const char*`, and you should leave the type of `out` alone. There is also no need to cast string literals to `const char*`; that's the implicit conversion and its only effect is to hide type problems.

Comment: Change `char* in` to `const char* in`. Also, remove all four of those dangerous and unnecessary casts. One is even incorrect

Comment: I tried to change the type of parameter `in` from `char *` to `const char *` (added that in question) and got both of mentioned errors. Also I understood about tree unnecessary casts (integer and string literals). But what's wrong with `malloc`?

Comment: ***But what's wrong with malloc*** [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new)