# Why gnulib uses `*(void **) ptrptr` instead of proper, and without cast, usage

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I came across `int  safe_alloc_realloc_n (void  *ptrptr,  size_t size, size_t count)` function, at [Github/scratchpadRepos/gnulib](https://github.com/scratchpadRepos/gnulib/blob/master/lib/safe-alloc.c), which is actually an older version of the [official gnulib](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib),

In that function, I found `*(void **)ptrptr` weird,
With or without the cast, it contains a memory address, so is there any point of casting here,

Comment: `Also, may i ask` Please one question per question.

Comment: for the first question c++ seems to be not relevant because it is c

Comment: And for the second question, no, `malloc` and `new` are not equivalent. `malloc` is just at the halfway of the road, `new` contructs an object while `malloc` doesn't. C and C++ are not the same language, otherwise they wouldn't be two separate languages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new

Comment: `*(void **)ptrptr = NULL` (where `ptrptr` is a `void *`) treats `ptrptr` as the address of a `void *`.   Just doing `*ptrptr = NULL` won't work, since `void *` is special - in both C or C++ - and cannot be dereferenced.     Also, your usage of `NEW` is not equivalent to operator `new` in C++ - `malloc()` only allocates raw memory, whereas a `new` expression in C++ both allocates raw memory AND (given an appropriate `new` expression) initialises it (e.g. by calling a constructor of a class type) so that memory contains a valid object.

Comment: My apology, to waste your time, by mentioning cpp, i have updated the answer now

Comment: Dereferencing a `void *` (which is what `*ptrptr` does) is diagnosable error.   Dereferencing other pointer types (e.g. `void **`, `int *`, etc) is not a diagnosable error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why gnulib uses `*(void **) ptrptr` instead of proper, and without cast, usage

The argument is a `void *`, doing `*ptrptr` would try to assign to `void`. `void` is a void, you can't assign to it.

On POSIX systems you can cheat, all pointers have the same alignment and size. You can do `int *a; *(void **)&a = some_value;`, although such code is very invalid according to C language.

The function takes a generic pointer `void *` and then assigns to the pointer, so that you can `int *a; safe_alloc_realloc_c(&a, ...)` pass a pointer to any pointer type. Otherwise you would have to create a separate function for every type `safe_alloc_realloc_c_int(int **, ...)` `safe_alloc_realloc_c_char(char **, ...)` etc.

> Have same functionality,

No. `malloc` allocates memory. `new` allocates the memory and creates an object, calling object constructor and starting object lifetime.

Comment: Rather, on _Linux_ you can cheat since it relies so deeply on both documented and undocumented non-standard extensions of gcc that it will instantly crumble into pieces if ever compiled with a different compiler. I don't think anything in POSIX as such requires the use of dirty casts.

Comment: @Lundin Not just Linux though; basically any combination of (GCC | clang | ICC) + (libc | musl), wherever that may run. And I think Kamil has a point in that POSIX *essentially* requires this behaviour for some of its functions to be usable, IIRC (but I can't think of an example right now; probably something with pthreads).

Comment: @KonradRudolph There's the dirty hack of casting a value or pointer into a void* for the pthread callback and then cast it back, but that's just abuse of the POSIX API rather than something encouraged by POSIX.

Comment: The problems start from the function prototype. Then it is only getting worse.

Comment: @Lundin Actually I think I misremembered that; I was probably thinking of the function pointer/object pointer equivalence in POSIX (via e.g. `dlsym`) which is undefined in C.

Comment: Yes— `dlsym()` is a troublemaker.