# Function returning array with rubbish values

Tags: c++, algorithm, reverse, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition

I am trying to allocate an array on the heap so that I can return it as the output of a function that is supposed to reverse the order of the elements. when I run the program, however, The first element of array1 is missing and I get rubbish at the start of array2. Am I declaring the array wrong?

Also, since I am working with dynamic memory, must I release the memory with the delete command or will it be deleted automatically as it is within the local scope of the reverseArray function?

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned *reverseArray(unsigned *arr)
{
    unsigned *output = (unsigned*) malloc(sizeof(int)*5);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        output[i] = arr[5 - i];

    return output;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned array1[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

    unsigned *array2 = reverseArray(array1);

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << array2[i] << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is

```
32751 50 40 30 20
```

Comment: `5 - i` should be `5 - i - 1` (to get 0 based index) or simply `4 - i`.

Comment: See [In what cases do I use malloc and/or new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-and-or-new)

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int*`, and there are very few cases when you should be using `malloc` in high level programming like this. I'd suggest you use more modern learning materials.

Comment: Forget that C-style arrays exist in the language. Use `std::array` and `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, your index was wrong: `5-i` accesses fields 5,4,3,2,1. Leaving out `0` and much more importantly, accessing past the end of the array.

However, you can just use the standard library's [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) function template, which even operates in-place:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned array1[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

    std::reverse(std::begin(array1), std::end(array1));

    for(auto const& value: array1)
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

In case you want to keep the original array, use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which has a handy copy constructor:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<unsigned,5> const array1{10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    auto array2 = array1;

    std::reverse(std::begin(array2), std::end(array2));

    for(auto const& value: array1) std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for(auto const& value: array2) std::cout << value << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This has the advantage that no dynamic allocations are performed. `std::reverse` also operates entirely in-place, so there is nothing to clean up afterwards.

If you have an array of values that is *not* known at compile time, like your `array1` is, you can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which takes care of mopping up memory after you're done with it. `std::reverse` works with that as well.

Comment: Good answer, just missing `#include <iterator>` for `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

Comment: @sweenish Yes, thank you. Missed that one. For the second version they come with `<array>` but not for raw arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
output[i] = arr[5 - i];
```

Since `i` will get the values [0,1,2,3,4], `5 - i` will get the values [5,4,3,2,1].
In order to get 0 based indices ([4,3,2,1,0]) as required, you need to **subtract 1**:

```
output[i] = arr[4 - i]; // 5 - i - 1
```

**A side note:**
It's better to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamic arrays in C++.
Among other advantages, it will save you the need (and potential bugs) of manual `new` and `delete` (or `malloc` and `free` although they are altogether discouraged in c++ in favor of `new`/`delete` in the rare case they are needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a C++ program then use the operator `new` instead of the C function `malloc`.

For example

```
unsigned *output = new unsigned[5];
```

And you always should free all the allocated memory when it is not required any more.

Your function has undefined behavior because in this statement

```
    output[i] = arr[5 - i];
```

when `i` is equal to `0` there is an access to memory outside the passed array because in this case the statement is look like

```
    output[0] = arr[5];
```

Also the function parameter should have the qualifier `const` because passed arrays are not changed within the function.

Also using the magic number `5` within the function makes the function useless.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

unsigned * reverseArray( const unsigned *arr, size_t n )
{
    unsigned *output = nullptr;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        output = new unsigned[n];

        for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        {
            output[i] = arr[n - i - 1];
        }
    }

    return output;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned array1[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    const std::size_t N = std::size( array1 );

    unsigned *array2 = reverseArray( array1, N );

    for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << array2[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    delete [] array2;

    return 0;
}
```

Pay attention to that there is standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy` that can be used. Using this algorithm the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>    

int main()
{
    unsigned array1[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    const std::size_t N = std::size( array1 );
    unsigned array2[N];

    std::reverse_copy( std::begin( array1 ), std::end( array1 ),
                       std::begin( array2 ) );

    for ( const auto &item : array2 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

There is no need to allocate dynamically a new array. Otherwise you could write for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>    

int main()
{
    unsigned array1[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    const std::size_t N = std::size( array1 );
    unsigned *array2 new unsigned[N];

    std::reverse_copy( std::begin( array1 ), std::end( array1 ),
                       array2 );

    for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << array2[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete [] array2;

    return 0;
}
```

If you need to reverse the source array then use another algorithm `std::reverse` the following way

```
std::reverse( std::begin( array1 ), std::end( array1 ) );
```

Comment: If you write a c++ program you shouldn't use 'new' except for rare special cases, but rather make_unique.

Comment: @cptFracassa Before using smart pointers you should learn how to use operators new and delete.

Comment: Agree to disagree on that. I think people should learn *about* them, but should only *write* code that fits in the current idioms of the language. Meaning my students would see `new` and `delete`, I would explain what they do, why it's a headache and huge cause for bugs, and here's what you're expected to write. Generally, students learning C++ have to *see* a lot of old stuff and have it explained, but they need to learn the safer ways of doing the same things.